# How can Jenkins block Merge without full approved pull request from TFS

Tags: git, jenkins, tfs

I want Jenkins to block any merge process without getting approved from pull requests. For now merge is completed by Jenkins but i have no PR builder in Jenkins. PRs are creating manually.

I just want Jenkins to access to TFS and read the pull requests results. According results, Jenkins should be able to merge or not. How can i control it?

Addition: Or How can I create link between PR completed key and Jenkins. When i click the competed button, is it possible Jenkins run my tests before merge?

Comment: Why your merge in in Jenkins and not in TFS PR (when you complete PR the merge occurs)?

Comment: I need to run some tests after PR.I know I would create Jenkins PR build. But running tests before PR is wasting my time. So i need Jenkins to run tests after PR. Then if test are ok, merge occurs.